# Clone a branch from repo and checkout with a local branch name

Tags: git, git-clone

`git clone <_url_> -b <_remote_branch_name_>` clones the repo and checks out the branch that I specify in the argument. However, I end up with a local branch with the same name as the remote branch.

Is there a way to specify the local name of the branch that is checked out after cloning ?

Comment: To clarify: is it the case that your server has a branch named X and you want to create a local branch named Y with the upstream set to X? Or do you want a local branch named X with no upstream which points to the same commit as X?

Comment: Server branch = X , local cloned branch after checkout = Y with upstream set to point to X. This is what I am looking for.

Comment: I gave two options in my comment. Which of those do you mean?

Comment: reposting : Server branch = X , local cloned branch after checkout = Y with upstream set to point to X. This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible using `git clone` but the branch can be renamed after cloning:

```
git clone <_url_> -b <_remote_branch_name_>
git branch -m <_remote_branch_name_> <_local_branch_name_>
```

Comment: This works. Just wanted to know if there is any way of doing it using the clone options.